# How to get GCM ID stored on device

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a app for Android, and I need to get the GCM RegID stored on Device (the registration already completed) and send to my sql server. How I can get the Reg ID stored?

Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);` from your `Activity` or other `Context`. If it returns the empty string, you do not have a registration ID. If it returns a non-empty string, that is the registration ID.

Note that this is also delivered to your `GCMIntentService` in its `onRegistered()` callback method.